# django run server error with mysql

Tags: python, mysql, django, python-2.7

After I solve the issue with "image not found" when I run `python manage.py syncdb` by adding "export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/mysql/lib/" into .bash_profile.
  The problem comes with `python manage.py runserver`
  Does anyone know how to solve OSError(Errno 20)?

```
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
October 07, 2014 - 18:19:56
Django version 1.8, using settings 'dbtest.settings'
Starting development server at http:/127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 330, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 322, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/base.py", line 363, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/base.py", line 412, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 80, in handle
    self.run(**options)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 89, in run
    autoreload.main(self.inner_run, None, options)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8-py2.7.egg/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 320, in main
    reloader(wrapped_main_func, args, kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8-py2.7.egg/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 286, in python_reloader
    reloader_thread()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8-py2.7.egg/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 262, in reloader_thread
    change = fn()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8-py2.7.egg/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 200, in code_changed
    stat = os.stat(filename)
OSError: [Errno 20] Not a directory: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-macosx-10.9-intel.egg/MySQLdb/converters.py'
```

Answer (score 0):

I just realize that I install both mysql-python and mysql-connector-python packages.
By changing the database 'ENGINE' setting from 'django.db.backends.mysql' to 'mysql.connector.django', the issue is solved.

Lesson learned here: I should probably use virtualenv to try different python package.